# how i can create a delegate for an Office Com Proxy method in C#?

Tags: c#, com, interop

the question is related to following thread:
[Access COM vtable from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3504848/access-com-vtable-from-c-sharp)

what i have to do is calling a method from a com object trough a method pointer from c#

i know a method pointer is not necessary but in this special case it is.

why i need the method pointer?

i want accessing the SetPlaceholderText method from Word.Content Control via latebinding.
all latebind features in .NET->COM use the Invoke method from the IDispatch interface, implemented from the com object. the Invoke method in the Word.ContentControl class has a bug! it works early bind beacuse the interop runtime avoid Invoke and use method pointers.
(thats what i want also to handle the problem). its impossible to use the method with vb latebinding, c# dynamics or GetType().Invoke...

i use the code from the linked posting as template:

```cs
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public delegate void SetPlaceHolderTextCallback(
      [MarshalAs(28)] [In] object BuildingBlock = null,
      [MarshalAs(28)] [In] object Range = null, 
      [MarshalAs(19)] [In] string Text = "");

object contentControl = GetContentControlProx();
IntPtr comPtr = Marshal.GetComInterfaceForObject(contentControl,
                                         typeof(ContentControl));
IntPtr vTable = Marshal.ReadIntPtr(comPtr); 

int start = Marshal.GetStartComSlot(typeof(ContentControl));
int end = Marshal.GetEndComSlot(typeof(ContentControl));

SetPlaceHolderTextCallback invoker = null;
ComMemberType mType = MemberTypes.Method;
for (int i = start; i < end; i++)
{
   System.Reflection.MemberInfo mi = 
   Marshal.GetMethodInfoForComSlot(typeof(ContentControl), i, ref mType);
   if (mi.Name == "SetPlaceholderText")
   {
      IntPtr methodPointer = Marshal.ReadIntPtr(vTable, i * 
                                  Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(IntPtr)));
      invoker = Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(methodPointer,
      typeof(SetPlaceHolderTextCallback)) as SetPlaceHolderTextCallback;
      break;
   }
}

invoker(Type.Missing, Type.Missing, "helloWorld");
```

The invoke fails with an AccessViolationException. i have no idea at the moment....

Comment: update: i found an interessted german link: jochen.jochen-manns.de/index.php/2007/03/03/com-wars-wenn-net-zu-schlau-ist

the blog entry told me, the first parameter in the delegate must be an adress pointer to the class instance. i'm confused :o

Answer (score 0):

seems like my problem is resolved.
the blog entry from jochen manns give me the answer.
the first parameter must be an IntPtr to the class intance.

```
<!-- language: lang-cs -->
    IntPtr adressPointer = Marshal.GetComInterfaceForObject(control, 
                                    typeof(Word.ContentControl));
    invoker(adressPointer, null, null, "helloWorld");
<!-- language: lang-cs -->
```

works !!!